# change hue/saturation of screen without using form background color

Tags: vb.net, winforms

in vb.net i would like to change the hue and saturation and darkness of the screen without using a form.

for example these two colors change the color of the screen directly (however i doubt they were programmed in vb.net)

http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/

http://colororacle.cartography.ch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try out the stereopsis program, but it looks to me like the ColorOracle program just takes a "snapshot" of the screen, re-colors it however, and then pops up a screen-size form with the image on it (which goes away when you click it).

This would be easy to do in .Net, but I'm guessing that you want your actual real live screen to change hue, and I'm not sure that's even possible (unless your monitor settings can be changed programatically in Windows).

Comment: hey the first link actually controls the colors of the screen with no problem

Comment: It sure does. I'm going to look into doing this from .Net, since it dovetails nicely with my own nefarious porpoises.